# Gitlab: How to edit VS code git credentials

Tags: git, gitlab

I've been trying to clone a project for an hour. The issue is that I initially entered incorrect credentials.

And then, when I try to clone, instead of asking me to enter the credentials, it reuses them, resulting in this:

> git clone https://gitlab.com/company_name/project_name.git
> c:\Users\ANONYMOUS\project_name --progress remote: HTTP Basic: Access
> denied. The provided password or token is incorrect, or your account
> has 2FA enabled, and you must use a personal access token instead of a
> password. See link to GitLab troubleshooting. fatal: Authentication
> failed for 'https://gitlab.com/company_name/project_name.git/'

I've searched everywhere for how to reset them, but nothing. If you know how to do it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I try to guess how VSCode manages passwords, so I suggest you to try with:

1. Close VSCode.
2. Issue: `git config --unset credential.helper`.
3. Start VSCode again.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by opening windows credentials manager and fixing the credentials mistake.